# Fetching Wordpress Private Posts, Public Posts Via Default REST API Endpoint

Tags: rest-api

My question on this particular topic is to ask whether it is possible to fetch private posts along with public posts using the Default WordPress REST API Endpoint for posts.
The endpoint is '/wp/v2/posts'. Even when I try to pass parameters in the endpoint URL to get the private posts along with public ones. It throws me 'Forbidden Message and A code', I looked for a lot of solutions online, and in StackOverflow platform. Could not find a proper exact to the point answer solution.

Suggestions would be very helpful for this particular problem.

Comment: If you want private posts the request needs to be authenticated. See here: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication

Comment: So is this the only way to fetch private posts?Are there no alternatives?

Comment: If posts are private why wouldn’t you want authentication to be required. You could add code so that private posts are included, but then they’re not private anymore. Why do you need to query private posts?

Comment: @JacobPeattie basically there is a chatbox that renders posts, to load the posts we used the WordPress default rest API to deliver the payload on the chatbox. Now by default if a post is private it should be available to the admin and editor. But on the chatbox when I am logged in as an admin or editor. It doesn't show the private posts, so we want to have private posts as well through the API

Comment: @CupidChakma, the documentation stated, "If no nonce is provided the API will set the current user to 0, turning the request into an **unauthenticated request**, even if you’re logged into WordPress", so even if you're logged into WordPress as admin or editor (that can view private posts), private posts won't be included unless your API request is authenticated. And that can be changed via filter/hook, but that means everyone would be able to view the private posts, e.g. by visiting the request/API URL. So unless you want that to happen, you should just authenticate your request.

Comment: @SallyCJ very nice explaination. Thank you now i have a solution in hand